# apply sorting in stuff, stuff distinct and order by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I need to combine rows with same value into one using STUFF operator. I archived the rows concatenation, but sequence of values is not correct.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2f420/1/0

as you see on result window, TypeB is next to TypeA, but sequence of Amount values is not corresponding the Type values, where 0.09K should be next to 3k

[image]

How to make STUFF of distinct values and save the sequence (order by rn) ?

```
create table SomeTable (Code int, Type nvarchar(50), Amount nvarchar(50), Date datetime);

insert into SomeTable VALUES(20, 'TypeA', '12k', cast('01/01/2019' as datetime));
insert into SomeTable VALUES(20, 'TypeA', '11k', cast('01/01/2018' as datetime));
insert into SomeTable VALUES(22, 'TypeA', '17k', cast('01/02/2017' as datetime));
insert into SomeTable VALUES(22, 'TypeA', '17k', cast('01/01/2017' as datetime));
insert into SomeTable VALUES(25, 'TypeB', '0.09k', cast('01/02/2019' as datetime));
insert into SomeTable VALUES(25, 'TypeA', '3k', cast('01/01/2019' as datetime));

with t as (

  select 
      row_number() over(partition by st.Code order by st.Date) as rn,
      st.Code, 
      st.Type, 
      st.Amount, 
      st.Date 
  from SomeTable st
)

select 
  t1.Code,
  stuff((select distinct ',' + t.Type from t 
         where t.Code = t1.Code
         for XML path('')), 1,1, '') as Type,
  stuff((select distinct ',' + t.Amount from t 
         where t.Code = t1.Code
         for XML path('')), 1,1, '') as Amount,
  t1.Date
from t as t1
where t1.rn = 1
order by t1.Date
```

Comment: Please show your sql

Comment: follow the link please http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2f420/1/0

Comment: And once again I see some misconceptions about this concatenation pattern... The concatenation is done by the SELECT...FOR XML subquery. The STUFF is just a string function used here for removing the first separator from the result. ;)

Comment: Did you try adding an `ORDER BY` clause inside the `FOR XML` sub queries?

Comment: @SalmanA yes, i tried, the problem it break the distinct rule, finally i get something like this: TypeA,TypeA and 17k, 17k

Comment: Using `DISTINCT` seems incorrect. If you have data such as `typea, 10k`, `typea, 11k`, `typeb, 11k` then the result will contain `typea,typeb | 10k,11k` but clearly the 10k and 11k do not correspond to the types.

Comment: @Z.R.T. Are you sure you want to use STUFF for this, if you're working on SSMS 2016+ then you could use String_agg function

Comment: @MidhunJoy i use SQL Server 2008

Comment: @MidhunJoy `string_agg` was introduced in 2017 version, not 2016, and the SSMS version has nothing to do with it - it's the SQL Server version that's important.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Noted

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apply sorting to any result in SQL is done by using the `order by` clause.
It's not the `stuff` function that's giving you a hard time, it's the fact that you didn't specify an `order by` to the subqueries.
Without and `order by` clause, the subqueries returns the records in an arbitrary order - and this is why you get the result you are getting now.
Please note, however, that since the order of the results is arbitrary, you might get a different result next time you run the query.

Therefor, you must specify an `order by` clause in your subqueries that generates the C.S.V columns.

Now I'm not really sure what order are you expecting, but it's probably either sorting by `rn` or by `rn desc` (based on the image I think it's the first).
However, there is a trick here - since you want distinct values of `type` and `amount`, you can't simply use `rn` in the `order by` clause - SQL Server will raise the following error:

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

So, the trick is to not use `distinct`, but instead, use `group by`, and not use `rn` in the `order by` clause, but `max(rn)`. This way, you get `TypeA,TypeB` and `3k,0.09k` - and it will be consistent.

Having said all that - here's a revised version of your code (the cte remains the same):

```
select  t1.Code,
  stuff((
            select ','+ t.Type
            from t 
            where t.Code = t1.Code
            group by t.Type
            order by max(rn) 
            for XML path('')
        ), 1,1, '') as Type,
  stuff((select ',' + t.Amount 
         from t 
         where t.Code = t1.Code
         group by  t.Amount 
         order by max(rn) 
         for XML path('')), 1,1, '') as Amount,
  t1.Date
from t as t1
where t1.rn = 1
order by t1.Date
```

And the results:

```
Code    Type            Amount      Date
22      TypeA           17k         2017-01-01
20      TypeA           11k,12k     2018-01-01
25      TypeA,TypeB     3k,0.09k    2019-01-01
```

**NOTE** [Salman's comment to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56626671/apply-sorting-in-stuff/56627643#comment99826318_56626671) (which I've only seen now) has a very valid point - `distinct` might not be a good option here at all.
In a scenario where you had `TypeA, TypeB, TypeA` with corresponding amounts `10K, 11K, 12K` -
If you do distinct, the result would be `TypeA, TypeB` and amounts `10K, 11K, 12K` - and it would be impossible to tell which amount belongs to which type.

Comment: Please note the final paragraph of my answer as well as Salman's comment. It's important. I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

Put order by into stuff segment:

```
 select 
  t1.Code,
  stuff((select distinct top 100 percent  ',' + t.Type from t 
         where t.Code = t1.Code order by ',' + t.Type 
         for XML path('')), 1,1, '') as Type,
  stuff((select distinct ',' + t.Amount from t 
         where t.Code = t1.Code
         for XML path('')), 1,1, '') as Amount,
  t1.Date
from t as t1
where t1.rn = 1
order by t1.Date
```

Comment: try now, changed it a bit

Comment: TypeA - 3k, TypeB - 0.09k the result should be TypeA,TypeB and 3k, 0.09k

Comment: Ill leave it up to you to apply the logic

Comment: @Z.R.T. Matching linked CSVs in different columns like you want can be quite difficult in SQL. And if you finally succeed in doing it, the results might become difficult to read and match, especially when there are many CSVs (more than five or so) in the columns. I would personally consider to switch to another data retrieval/presentation strategy here, like splitting them in separate columns, or creating some kind of grouped rows in the client application or report (if the CSVs can be very dynamic).

Answer (score 1):

How about trying like this?

```
with t as (
  select 
      row_number() over(partition by st.Code order by st.Date) as rn,
      st.Code, 
      st.Type, 
      st.Amount, 
      st.Date 
  from SomeTable st
),
t2 as (
  select distinct top 100 percent
      st.code,
      st.type,
      st.amount
  from SomeTable st
  order by st.code, st.type, st.amount
)

select 
  t1.Code,
  stuff((select distinct ',' + t2.Type from t2 
         where t2.Code = t1.Code
         for XML path('')), 1,1, '') as Type,
  stuff((select ',' + t2.Amount from t2 
         where t2.Code = t1.Code
         for XML path('')), 1,1, '') as Amount,
  t1.Date
from t as t1
where t1.rn = 1
order by t1.Date
```

Comment: thank you very much for you answer, it is working as i need , but solution with grouping looks more appropriate

Comment: This answer is wrong. The `top 100 percent...order by` will not effect the order of the results returned from queries of the common table expression - since database tables are unordered by nature. That's the reason why SQL Server raise an error when you are attempting to use `order by` without `top` (or `for xml/ for josn`) on common table expressions, views and derived table - It is a misfortune that the T-SQL parser is not strict enough to fail a query using the `top 100 percent` "trick" - but that doesn't mean it will do what you expect it to do.

Comment: For more information, read [SQL: SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT is a code smell for SQL Server](https://blog.greglow.com/2018/06/11/sql-select-top-100-percent-is-a-code-smell-for-sql-server/) As well as Aaron Bertrand's [answer here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21434/why-does-order-by-not-belong-in-a-view) And a blog post by Microsoft's query optimizer team entitled [TOP 100 Percent ORDER BY Considered Harmful.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/queryoptteam/2006/03/24/top-100-percent-order-by-considered-harmful/)